# Is S-100 alive?

Tags: history, z80, s-100

1) Is S-100 still supported or available for serious home brew? Does anyone still actively sell ***new*** boards, cases, designing, support, etc? If not, then about what year did S-100 development stop?

2) If S-100 is still supported what is the most popular OS and basic configuration (if there is one)?

*[ I built my first computer as a Z-80/CPM based Altair system (~1978) and eventually donated it to a business in about 1990. As I remember it, a company named Morrow (or something like that) still was selling business systems at least to the 1987-88 period and I think S-100 was still going well enough for advertisers in the computer magazines. My system consisted of a case that supported about 20 cards and had a power supply that brought the weight to about 40-50lbs. I had another case that held two 8in floppy drives and weighed about the same. Both cases where approximately 18" square and 10" high!]*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are still a few communities using and developing S-100 boards. A good place to start is [the S100 computers](http://www.s100computers.com/) site, which lists [a number of new S-100 boards](http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Index%20Page.htm) which can be ordered and used to build new S-100 systems. [The corresponding forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/s100computers) is very active.

I think the most popular S-100 configuration is still a Z-80 with CP/M, albeit with newer peripherals — [VGA output and PC keyboard input](http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/Console%20IO%20Board/Console%20IO%20Board.htm), and [IDE storage](http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/IDE%20Board/My%20IDE%20Card.htm). You can also build DOS systems, *e.g.* using [a 486 CPU board](http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/80486%20Board/80486%20CPU%20Board.htm) and [SRAM board](http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/80386%20-%2032MG%20RAM%20Board/32MG%20Static%20RAM%20Board.htm), or even a PDP-11 clone with [this PDP-11 CPU board](http://s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/PDP11%20V2%20Board/PDP11%20Board%20V2.htm) and [associated support board](http://s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/PDP11%20Support%20Board/PDP11%20Support%20%20Board.htm).

Comment: Interesting... What are the S-100 systems being used for?

Comment: Glad I hit reload before posting, as your answer already includes all links I also had. Thanks.

Comment: @jwzumwalt mostly for hobbyist exploration I think, although I imagine some of these boards might be used to keep old industrial systems working!

Comment: There is also the [Vintage S-100 Computer Enthusiasts](https://www.facebook.com/groups/s100computer/) Facebook Group.